# how to connect to 2 different ftp servers transfer files using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have to copy file from one FTP location to other FTP location ? can i do it using shell script ?

I have tried this

But for this i have to excute the script as source location

Copy files from once linux system to other

```
scp source folder  username@hostname:destination
```

Eg

```
scp /ep-data/pcats/20130122/50201/20130122200900085_97_101_28/upload/* pcats@xxx.com:/home/pcats/Tay_Fra
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The ftp protocol permits you to open a control connection (port 21) to ftp1:21 and another control connection to ftp2:21 through your client. Over the control connection you can ask ftp1 to send a file directly to ftp2, without passing through your client. Data is passed over port 20. I think the question is, How can I pass a file from ftp1 to ftp2, without downloading the file to my current computer! -- THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION --

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with scp for this purpose?  If you're looking to download the file to your own computer and upload it again you can still use scp.  If you need it to work on Windows you can use [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) .

Comment: My requirement is to upload files one by one from 1st FTP  to 2nd FTP(connect and disconnect after each file is transferred) Using Shell script.